# Determining ways of splitting change

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and am interested in ways to improve my solution to the problem "Given an amount of money (in cents), determine all the ways to make change given a list of denominations".

```
change :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
change amt [] = [[]]
change amt [d] = [replicate (quot amt d) d]
change amt (d:denoms) =
 if d <= amt then
   reverse [0..(quot amt d)] >>= \x ->
     [(replicate x d) ++ c | c <- (change (amt - (x*d)) denoms)]
  else
    change amt denoms

changeUS amt = change amt [25, 10, 5, 1]

-- *Main> changeUS 29
-- [[25,1,1,1,1],[10,10,5,1,1,1,1],[10,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[10,5,5,5,1,1,1,1],[10,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[10,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1],[5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

One problem with this solution is it assumes the lowest denom will be 1. Otherwise, the `change amt [d]` case would be incorrect. I could add an `if/then` to make sure `amt` is evenly divisible by `d` in that case, but it's beginning to get a little verbose, and I think that case isn't even necessary in a better solution.

Comment: At the cost of some efficiency, you could remove the special case for a single denomination, and have two base cases, `change 0 _ = [[]]` and `change _ [] = []`. If you want it efficient, you need to keep the special case for the last denomination, but if that is larger than 1, you may still take a lot of costly dead branches before. Avoiding that would need some math determining what sorts of sums you can generate at all from the remaining denominations. For small amounts, that would be more costly than the dead-ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By far the simplest way to do this is just brute force.

```
-- assumes the denominations are distinct. If they aren't, the
-- return value is ambiguous
change :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
change _  0 = [[]]
change [] _ = []
change xxs@(x:xs) n | n >= x    = map (x:) (change xxs (n - x)) ++ change xs n
                    | otherwise = change xs n
```

It's completely immune to cases where a greedy approach doesn't work, it doesn't care if the input list is sorted or not, and the only reason it fails when denominations are not distinct is that the output format doesn't distinguish between different inputs in that case. If you changed the output type to distinguish between differing inputs with the same denomination, the same algorithm would work.

It's potentially slow in cases with a lot of branches, but that's not likely in change-making problems. It's also productively lazy, thus able to produce output incrementally if the consumer can do anything meaningful with partial output.

Comment: Nice! It's great to see this style; feels very idiomatic.